# @csrf is not working in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, csrf-protection

I am following this tutorial on Laravel and I've noticed that I cannot use the @csrf command, but others can use it effectively. But, I can use the {{ csrf_field() }} for the csrf token. I would like to know the reason why. Thanks.

Here's my screenshot on using the @csrf command: [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOss.png)

Here's my index.blade.php

```
       <form action="{{ route('contact.store') }}" method="post">

            @csrf

            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="username" placeholder="Username | Email | Phone Number" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Please provide a username
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="name" id="password" placeholder="" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Please provide a password
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <input type="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: because it is introduced later. You can use `{{ csrf_field() }}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no @csrf in 5.4, you must use

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Instead, @csrf is available in laravel 5.6

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

@csrf argument came to blade with 5.6

you need to use  `csrf_field()` method instead @csrf

for more information check out [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf)

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5.4 only available
refer to this link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

And Laravel 5.6 available
refer to this link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf

```
@csrf
```

Answer (score 0):

if you used to laravel framework version **5.6, 5.5** or less than version 5.5
you should write **`{{ csrf_field() }}`**, but if you used to laravel framework version **`5.7, 5.8`** or bigger than version 5.7 you should write **`@csrf`**

> Laravel 5.5, 5.6 => write {{ csrf_field() }}

> Laravel 5.7, or bigger than 5.7 => write @csrf